# Make panel scroll horizontally only, not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a panel in the left side that I want it to scroll horizontally only but is not working. I went into the panels properties and set ScrollBars to horizontal and it shows but it does not work. Picture is below.

```
  <asp:Panel ID="panelButtons" runat="server"  Direction="LeftToRight" 
         CssClass="leftPanel" ScrollBars="Horizontal" ></asp:Panel>
```

[image]

Comment: What result do you see?  No scrollbars at all?

Comment: Try assigning an explicit `Width` value on the `Panel` and let us know if that helps.

Comment: @DavidTansey I have tried that. What happens is the vertical scroll bar appears when I set a width, I want the horizontal scroll bar instead.
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are try using nested Panels and explicitly set Width of both panels.

```
<asp:Panel ID="panelContainer" runat="server"  Direction="LeftToRight" CssClass="leftPanelContainer" ScrollBars="Horizontal" Width="300px;">
  <asp:Panel ID="panelButtons" runat="server"  Direction="LeftToRight" CssClass="leftPanel" ScrollBars="Horizontal" Width="1000px">
    LEFT PANEL
  </asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: You can play with panelContainer width to find proper width. If you are using % for your right panel then you should use % for leftPanelContainer as well.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this with css: http://jsfiddle.net/8HJ4v/

The overflow properties are the important parts:

```
overflow-x:scroll;
overflow-y:hidden;
```

Comment: Do you have a width set for the container div? Try creating a jsfiddle to show the problem.